# Are there prebuilt architectures for decoder?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders

I am building Variatonal Autoencoder and right now for encoder I am using EffNetB0 architecture, which is simple to implement into encoder. For decoder, I have built my own architecture with 8 CNN filters. Results are quite good, but still I believe that decoder is too weak and would like to try a deeper network.

It would take tons of time to find the right architecture for decoder, so my question, is there any prebuilt architectures which I could use for decoder?

For example, for encoder it's possible to use any already prebuilt architecture, but for decoder, the whole architecture would need to be reversed. Are there any solutions?